# Wifi connection with canon pixma ip7250

Tags: wireless, 18.04, canon

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and i have a problem with installation of printer Canon Pixma ip7250. I have already read some comments about it, but it did not work for me. The printer shows that it is connected with my router, but my computer finds it only with LAN cable. Could someone help me?

Comment: You may have some WiFi isolation setting in the router.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having had a similar problem connecting my Wi-Fi printer. After a whole day of fumbling around, I discovered the type of security for Wi-Fi in my router was obsolete. I chose "WPA2-PSK/AES" and it worked for me.

Comment: i checked it by me, it seems to be ok, like by you

Comment: Hope that can help: https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/pixma_printer_wireless_connection_setup/ip7250_printer_wireless_connection_setup/